# String and number produce different results

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Holidays::USFederal;

if ( is_usfed_holiday( '2018', '01', '01' ) ) {    # strings
    print "holiday\n";
}
else {
    print "not holiday\n";
}

if ( is_usfed_holiday( 2018, 1, 1 ) ) {            # numbers
    print "holiday\n";
}
else {
    print "not holiday\n";
}

exit;
```

#### output

```
not holiday
holiday
```

I thought Perl was a context-based language and that strings were automatically used as numbers when needed. This cost me a little debugging time today. I'm no expert, but this confuses me.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Note that the taint flag `-T` is useless on the shebang line.

Comment: @Borodin I verified the taint flag on my system using ${^TAINT} and conducted a test. It works and produces the desired effect. Is "useless" a portability thing?

Comment: By the time perl reads the shebang line, it is too late in the compilation process to apply tainting. This is a fatal error unless `-T` is also applied to the command line, in which case its appearance on the shebang line is irrelevant. I suppose you could say that it has some use because it prevents the code from being run without taint mode enabled, but it cannot enable the mode on its own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_usfed_holiday` uses `join($;, @_)` as the key to a hash. It therefore uses the stringification rather than the numification of its arguments.

Solutions:

```
is_usfed_holiday(0+$y, 0+$m, 0+$d)

is_usfed_holiday(map 0+$_, $y,$m,$d)
```

---

Someone should contact the author to raise the following issues:

- `is_usfed_holiday` should normalize its inputs to avoid the problem you encountered.
- The module shouldn't rely on the existing value of `$;`.

Also, some might find of a variant of `is_usfed_holiday` that takes the result of `localtime` (e.g. `is_usfed_holiday_time(localtime)`) useful.

Comment: As soon as I realized what was happening, I implemented the +0 solution. Thanks!